Vanishing Time for Wave Equation Robin Boundary Conditions
I am working on a problem from a book on hyperbolic PDEs. The problem is to consider a solution to the homogenous wave equation $(\partial^2_t - \partial^2_x)u=0$ on a spacetime cylinder $[a,b] \times (0, \infty)$ with the boundary conditions that $u(a,t) = 0, (\partial_t+\partial_x)u(b,t) = 0$. The first part of the problem is to show that $E(T)-E(0) = -\int_0^T (\partial_tu)^2(b,t)dt$ (where $E(t)$ as defined below is the standard energy for the wave equation). This I have done by integration by parts while integrating over the whole region. The second part is the part I am having difficulty with.
The second part asks to show that for $t>2(b-a), u = 0$. To me it seems that the thing to show is that $E(0) = \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b (\partial_tu)^2+(\partial_xu)^2 (x,0) dx \leq \int_0^t (\partial_tu)^2 (b,t)dt$ for $t$ as above. Equivalently since $(\partial_t u)^2(b,t) = (\partial_xu)^2(b,t)$ that $\int_a^b (\partial_tu)^2+(\partial_xu)^2 dx \leq \int_0^t (\partial_tu)^2 + \partial_x u)^2 dt$. I’m not sure how to proceed given that these integrals are in totally different variables. I have tried considering the double integral, Cauchy-Schwarz, and even basic integral bounds given the length of the interval, but none have worked. I would really appreciate a hint! :))

The general solution to $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2)u=0$ is
$$
u(x,t)=f(t-x)+g(t+x), \tag{1}
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary differentiable functions. It follows from the boundary condition $(\partial_t+\partial_x)u(b,t)=0$ that
$$
2g'(t+b)=0\quad(t>0),\quad\text{hence}\quad g(\xi)=C \quad(\xi>b). \tag{2}
$$
On the other hand, $u(a,t)=0$ implies
$$
f(t-a)+g(t+a)=0\quad(t>0),\quad\text{or}\quad 
f(\eta)=-g(\eta+2a)\quad(\eta>-a). \tag{3}
$$
In particular, it follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that
$$
f(\eta)=-C\quad\text{if}\quad\eta>b-2a. \tag{4}
$$
Now, $t>2(b-a)$ and $a\leq x\leq b$ imply $t+x>2(b-a)+a=b+(b-a)>b$ and $t-x>2(b-a)-b=b-2a$, hence, by $(2)$ and $(4)$,
$$
u(t,x)=f(t-x)+g(t+x)=-C+C=0\quad(t>2(b-a),\,a\leq x\leq b). \tag{5}
$$
